# Adjugate of composition

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

> I want to prove
> $$
> \operatorname{adj}(\psi\circ\phi)=\operatorname{adj}(\phi)\circ \operatorname{adj}(\psi).
> $$

I work with linear maps and not directly with matrices.
The definition of adjugate that I use can be seen in the first equality.

Finite dimension $n$.
$\delta$ is any skew symmetric $n$-form, that is a determinant form (unique up to a factor).

I've a complete proof for the case $\phi$ injective:
\begin{align*}
&\delta(v_1,\cdots,v_n)\phi\circ\operatorname{adj}(\psi\circ\phi)(v)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1} \delta\big(v,\psi\circ\phi(v_1),\cdots,\widehat{\psi\circ\phi(v_k)},\cdots, \psi\circ\phi(v_n)\big)\phi(v_k)\\
&= \delta(\phi(v_1),\cdots,\phi(v_n))\operatorname{adj}(\psi)(v).
\end{align*}
and then
\begin{align*}
&\delta(\phi(v_1),\cdots,\phi(v_n))\operatorname{adj}(\phi)\circ \operatorname{adj}(\psi)(v)\\
&\quad = \delta(v_1,\cdots,v_n)\big(\underbrace{\operatorname{adj}(\phi)\circ\phi}_{=\det(\phi)\operatorname{id} }\big)\circ\operatorname{adj}(\psi\circ\phi)(v)\\
&\quad = \delta(\phi(v_1),\cdots,\phi(v_n)) \operatorname{adj}(\psi\circ\phi)(v)
\end{align*}
The problem is that if $\phi$ is not injective $\delta(\phi(v_1),\cdots,\phi(v_n))$ is zero.

Probably the problem started at the beginning, as I applied $\phi$.

Any hint on how do I get the general proof?

Comment: If the underlying field is $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$, you can make an argument via continuity. Setting that approach aside, I think it would be helpful to prove as an intermediate step that for $n \geq 2$, 
$$
\operatorname{adj}(\phi) = 0 \iff \operatorname{rank}(\phi) \leq n-2.
$$
Perhaps we need the stronger result relating the adjugate of $\phi$ to its image/kernel

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you for your comment. I'll try. You used "iff" , in my book the author has only one direction. Could confirm if also the following claim is "iff"? If $\operatorname{rk}(\phi)=n-1$, then  $\operatorname{Im}(\operatorname{adj}(\phi))=\operatorname{ker}(\phi)$.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed iff. It is easy that this is the case by considering matrices